# How can I exclude several individual values in json-server query

Tags: json-server

Using **_ne** operator, I can exclude a specific value.

```
GET /posts?id_ne=1
```

How can I exclude two or more individual values? I tried to chain the arguments as follows but it doesn't work.

```
GET /posts?id_ne=1&id_ne=5
```

Comment: according to https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/929, this feature is not yet supported by json-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix for multiple `_ne` operators has been added to `json-server` on 2. September 2019

see https://github.com/typicode/json-server/pull/1013